# Drupal 7 - Manage content based on roles + taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, roles

I have a site with two seperate areas. These areas should share the same views, content types and so on. This seperation should be done by two taxonomy terms (Area1, Area2).

Cause of the seperation, I have two roles: Area-1-Manager, Area-2-Manager.
If Area-1-Manager creates a node of a content type, the content will appear only in Area1 (done by views, so it's no problem). It should be impossible for Area-1-Manager to edit contents of Area2.

I've tried modules like TAC, Content Access but none of them seem to fit.
Is there any appropriate modules or methods to accomplish my structure?

**UPDATE:**
Finally, after days of research: The mighty module [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) takes care of it!